# How do you create a generic placeholder function in Java that takes functions as parameters to be used later?

Tags: java

I don't know how to articulate my question, but it is really simple.  I want to create a generic placeholder function that accepts one argument in an already existing function.  Let me give you an example.  To make things easy, suppose I wanted to know how long it takes for a function to execute in milliseconds.

```
public class Example{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int arr[] = {30, 8, 21, 19, 50, ... , n};
      //needs to accept a function with a parameter as an argument.
      timeTakenFunc(foo(arr), arr);
      timeTakenFunc(bar(arr), arr);
   }

   public static void foo(int A[]){
     //do stuff
   }

   public static void bar(int A[]){
     //do stuff
   } 

   public static void timeTakenFunc(/*what goes here?*/, int A[]){
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();

      //placeholder for foo and bar function here
      placeholder(A);

      long endTime = System.nanoTime();
      long duration = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000000);
      System.out.println("function took: " + duration + "milliseconds");

   }
}
```

Feel free to edit my question if it needs to be articulated better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Java 8 [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [functional interfaces](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces), you can accept a `Runnable` which performs some generic, unspecified action.

```
public static void timeTakenFunc(Runnable func) {
  long startTime = System.nanoTime();

  //placeholder for foo and bar function here
  func.run();

  long endTime = System.nanoTime();
  long duration = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000000);
  System.out.println("function took: " + duration + "milliseconds");
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```
timeTakenFunc(() -> foo(arr));
timeTakenFunc(() -> bar(arr));
```

This is shorthand for the pre-lambda equivalent of:

```
timeTakenFunc(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        foo(arr);
    }
});
timeTakenFunc(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        bar(arr);
    }
});
```

---

I removed the `int[] A` parameter as it's not necessarily needed here. As you can see, `arr` can be embedded inside the `Runnable`. If you wanted to keep it as a parameter then you could switch from `Runnable` to `Consumer<int[]>`.

```
public static void timeTakenFunc(Consumer<int[]> func, int[] A) {
  long startTime = System.nanoTime();

  //placeholder for foo and bar function here
  func.accept(A);

  long endTime = System.nanoTime();
  long duration = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000000);
  System.out.println("function took: " + duration + "milliseconds");
}
```

```
timeTakenFunc(arr -> foo(arr), A);
timeTakenFunc(arr -> bar(arr), A);
```

Or using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) with `::`, you can write:

```
timeTakenFunc(Example::foo, A);
timeTakenFunc(Example::bar, A);
```

Both of these are equivalent to this pre-lambda code:

```
timeTakenFunc(new Consumer<int[]>() {
    @Override public void accept(int[] arr) {
        foo(arr);
    }
});
timeTakenFunc(new Consumer<int[]>() {
    @Override public void accept(int[] arr) {
        bar(arr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using lambda expressions/method references

That's exactly the right type of job for `java.util.Function` introduced by Java 8. You can use *lambda expressions* to define your function, for example: `x -> x + 5`. Java 8 also supports *method references*. Say you have a **static** method called `myMethod` defined on class `MyClass`. If the method matches the signature of the interface that is expected by `timeTakenFunc` then you can write `timeTakenFunc(MyClass::myMethod)` as a shortcut.

Your signature could look like this:

```
public static <RESULT> void timeTakenFunc(Function<int[], RESULT>, int A[])
```

If you don't care about the results, you could use `Consumer`. If you don't need to take an input parameter, you can use `Runnable`.

### What if I'm not using Java 8 ?

First of all, Java 8 was a great addition to the language so you should consider using it. Apart from that, it's still fairly easy to do what you want but you'll need to do the work manually instead of letting the compiler do it for you.

Basically, you would start by defining an interface:

```
public interface IntArrayProcessor {
     void process(int[] arr);
}
```

Then, you would need to extend and instantiate the interface either by writing explicit classes or using anonymous classes:

```
IntArrayProcessor processor = new IntArrayProcessor() {
    @Override
    void process(int[] arr) {
       // calculate the sum of the array    
    } 
}
```

Finally, you would pass this object around and call the `process` method. The only problem with this approach is that it's very verbose compared to the syntax allowed by Java 8, but it's exacty what the compiler does when it sees a lambda expression or a method reference: it generates a new synthetic, anonymous class on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Java 8's new [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) and [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 30, 8, 21, 19, 50 };
        // needs to accept a function with a parameter as an argument.
        timeTakenFunc(Example::foo, arr);
        timeTakenFunc(Example::bar, arr);
    }

    public static void foo(int A[]) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public static void bar(int A[]) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public static void timeTakenFunc(Consumer<int[]> functionToMeasure,
            int A[]) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        // placeholder for foo and bar function here
        functionToMeasure.accept(A);

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000000);
        System.out.println("function took: " + duration + "milliseconds");

    }
}
```